# Populate ACO/ARO tables using existing data in CakePHP2

Tags: cakephp-2.0, acl

I am implementing a group(role) based ACL system for my CakePHP 2 app.

Now, I understand that ACL will automagically populate the aco/aro tables according to future changes in my data, but how can I fill those tables in respect to my existing data ? I have found very little documentation covering the way to manage existing data.

Here is how I split up my models.

The Group model is both requester and controlled. There are 4 groups.

```
public $actsAs = array(
        'Acl' => array('type' => 'both')
)
```

I have a User model, which is controlled and also binded to Group for the requester behavior. There are just under 11000 existing users.

```
public $actsAs = array(
        'Acl' => array('type' => 'controlled')
)

function bindNode($user) {
        return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
}
```

And I have a few other models that are controlled. The models are Client (260 entries), Note (just under 500 entries) and Registration (about 20000 entries).

```
public $actsAs = array(
        'Acl' => array('type' => 'controlled')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had misunderstood what qualifies as an ACO model. The only thing I really needed were the 4 ARO entries for Groups. The ACOs were useless as I do not need different access for aros to models of the same type.